# How to trigger a file download on click using Django and Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, pdf

I'm trying to produce a file download on click using Django and Javascript. I've nearly figured it out but I'm confused as to how to prevent Django from automaticall downloading the file once processing is complete. Here is my code:

views.py:

```
def translateFile(request) :
    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        source_language = request.POST.get('source_language')
        target_language = request.POST.get('target_language')


        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            uploaded_file = request.FILES['file']
            fs = FileSystemStorage()
            filename = fs.save(uploaded_file.name, uploaded_file)
            uploaded_file_path = fs.path(filename)
            
            file = (converter(uploaded_file_path, source_language, target_language))#translates file
            file_location = uploaded_file_path
            with open(file_location, 'rb') as f:
                file_data = f.read()
            
            response = HttpResponse(file_data, content_type='application/pdf')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + filename + '"'
            return response
```

Javascript:

```
const formData = new FormData(form);
        const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.open('POST', form.getAttribute('action'), true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {

            console.log("Ready state: ", xhr.readyState);
            console.log("Status: ", xhr.status);

            if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xhr.status === 200) {
                    loaderDiv.style.display = 'none';

                    const downloadArrowDiv = document.querySelector('#download-btn');
                    downloadArrowDiv.style.display = 'flex';
                    const responseText = document.querySelector('#response_text')
                    responseText.textContent = 'Click to download'


                    // File was successfully translated, you can update UI here
                    const downloadLink = document.querySelector('#response_text_anchor');
                    downloadLink.href = URL.createObjectURL(xhr.response);
                    downloadLink.download = formData.get('file').name;
                    downloadLink.click();
                } else {
                    // Handle error case
                    console.error('Error translating file');
                }
            }
        };

        xhr.responseType = 'blob';
        xhr.send(formData);
    });
```

HTML:

```
<button id="download-btn" class="upload" type="submit" name="download_file">
                            
                            <a id="response_text_anchor" href="" download><p id="response_text"></p></a>            
                        </button>
```

When I click it the file does download but it also auto downloads before clicking which is what I am trying to prevent.